# Set persistent SELinux file types under /run

Tags: centos, selinux

I set a file to a specific type using `semanage fcontext`, and using `restorecon` does properly set the file type. However, upon reboot, the type goes back the default. If I run `restorecon` again then it updates to its proper type. This file exists under `/run/`, is there a way to have this permissions change persist across reboots?

I ran `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/run/myfile`

Comment: `semanage fcontext` IS the way to make it persistent. Exactly what did you do? You need to be extremely specific and detailed. Edit your post and make it as long and detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed a file in `/run` but your `semanage fcontext` command references a path in `/var/run`. While that's a symlink to `/run` on modern systems, if you create a file in `/run` directly, that path will never match. Try fixing that; it should be `/run` and not `/var/run`.

Comment: Ok, so it won't let me do that. `conflicts with equivalency rule`

Comment: SELinux restorecon is smart enough to know that /var and/var/run are equivalent. My testing confirms the same results as the OP. I've noticed this before but didn't get tot he bottom of it. A file takes on the context of the parent directory even if these is a specific fcontext for it in the database and it takes a restrecon to set it correctly. I think I worked around it by putting the file in a directory and set the appropriate context on that.

Comment: @Iain The problem is not with restorecon, but when he creates the file initially.

Answer (score 0):

The SELinux fcontext configuration is for setting *default* selinux filecontext, which is applied by restorecon.

It may also applied by other programs, e.g. by Ansible when creating a file with a copy task that has `setype: _default`/`seuser: _default` specified.

Similar story when files/directories are created by systemd tmpfiles.

However, when the file matched by your fcontext rule is created by some service that doesn't care about SELinux default file contexts, then the context of the **parent directory** is inherited:

> New files inherit the type assigned to the directory where you created them.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/articles/6999267#file-context-10

Besides making your program looking up and applying default SELinux file context you can do one of the following:

1. Create a parent directory for your file under `/run` via Systemd's [`RuntimeDirectory=`](https://manpath.be/f37/5/systemd.exec#L1181) directive or the systemd [tmpfiles](https://manpath.be/f37/5/tmpfiles.d) configuration , create a fcontext rule for that directory `/var/run/yourserve` and configure your service to create `/run/yourservice/myfile` instead of `/run/myfile`. This should also be more secure, in general.
2. Declare a [file name transition](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sec-file-name-transition) in your custom SELinux policy module.